# Normalization of the harmonic oscillator propagator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, propagator, unitarity, normalization

The propagator of a quantum system is defined by $$\mathcal{K}(t,x;\,t_{0},x_{0})\,\equiv\,\left\langle x\right|\hat{U}(t,\,t_{0})\left|x_{0}\right\rangle.$$ In this notation, the unitarity demands that

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
&\hat{U}^{\dagger}(t,\,t_{0})\,\hat{U}(t,\,t_{0})\,=\,\left(\left|x_{2}\right\rangle \left\langle x_{2}\right|\hat{U}(t,\,t_{0})\left|x\right\rangle \left\langle x\right|\right)^{\dagger}\,\left|x_{1}\right\rangle \left\langle x_{1}\right|\hat{U}(t,\,t_{0})\left|x_{0}\right\rangle \left\langle x_{0}\right|\\
&=\,\left|x\right\rangle \mathcal{K}^{*}(t,x_{1};\,t_{0},x)\,\mathcal{K}(t,x_{1};\,t_{0},x_{0})\left\langle x_{0}\right|=\boldsymbol{\hat{1}}.
\end{split}\end{equation}

with implicit summation over any repeated index. So, unitarity is translated directly to the condition

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_{1}\mathcal{K}^{*}(t,x_{1};\,t_{0},x)\,\mathcal{K}(t,x_{1};\,t_{0},x_{0})\,=\,\delta(x-x_{0}),
\end{equation}

for any given $t$ and $t_{0}$ (the last condition can also be found in  W. Dittrich and M. Reuter, Classical and Quantum Dynamics, 6th ed, 2020; eq. (19.68)). However, for the Harmonic oscillator,

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
&\mathcal{K}(t,x_{1};\,t_{0},x_{0})=\,\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\pi i\sin[\omega(t-t_{0})]}}\exp\left(\frac{im\omega^{2}}{2\sin[\omega(t-t_{0})]}\left[(x_{0}^{2}+x_{1}^{2})\cos[\omega(t-t_{0})]-2x_{1}x_{0}\right]\right).
\end{split}\end{equation}

By using the above result,

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_{1}\mathcal{K}^{*}(t,x_{1};\,t_{0},x)\,\mathcal{K}(t,x_{1};\,t_{0},x_{0})=\,\frac{m\omega}{2\pi\sin[\omega(t-t_{0})]}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_{1}\exp\left(\frac{im\omega^{2}}{2\sin[\omega(t-t_{0})]}\left[(x_{0}^{2}-x^{2})\cos[\omega(t-t_{0})]+2x_{1}(x-x_{0})\right]\right).
\end{split}\end{equation}

How can I show that the above relation is satisfied?
I noticed that there are other posts discussing similar issues, but I'm particularly interested in $t>t_{0}$, which does not seems to be discussed.

Comment: The condition you are trying to prove is wrong.  An integration over **all** $x_1$s is warranted, as you missed the forrest for the trees. Simplify m=$\hbar$=ω=1, rationalize, and skip superfluous circular steps. The answer is a triviality, if only you take care to set up your problem properly. It won't cost you a thing to take $t_0=0$. [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Basic_examples:_propagator_of_free_particle_and_harmonic_oscillator).

Comment: @CosmasZachos: can you please explain why this condition that I'm trying to prove is wrong? it seems to be a trivial requirement.

Comment: @Buzz: No, this is what you get by multiplying two propagators. Half of the terms cancel due to the conjugation so it looks similar.. There was indeed a typo which I corrected. Thanks.

Comment: *Now* that you adduced the intermediate point integration, it's right, and toboggans to the simple answer breathlessly. See answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are essentially there:
$$  
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_{1}\mathcal{K}^{*}(t,x_{1};\,t_{0},x)\,\mathcal{K}(t,x_{1};\,t_{0},x_{0})\\
=   \exp\left(\frac{im\omega}{2\sin[\omega(t-t_{0})]} (x_{0}^{2}-x^{2})\cos[\omega(t-t_{0})]  \right) \\  \times
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!\!dx_{1}~~\frac{m\omega}{2\pi\sin[\omega(t-t_{0})]}~\exp\left(\frac{im\omega}{\sin[\omega(t-t_{0})]} x_{1}(x-x_{0}) \right).
 $$
The last line, the integral, is a plain Dirac δ, in turn trivializing the middle line, which is thus 1, netting you
$$
=\delta(x-x_0).
$$
You must not let the trees make you miss the forest. You had a superfluous $\omega$ in the exponent, which I corrected.

---

*Clarification w.r.t. comments and draft*: It is evident from the sophisticated draft you sent me that the question operates on a higher, unacknowledged, level of qualms. The simple-minded, conventional answer here assumes the customary $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int\!\!\frac{dx}{\epsilon}~ e^{-ixy/\epsilon} =2\pi \delta (y)$ which clearly troubles you. This is a far more sophisticated sub-question which possibly merits its own, self-standing question.

Comment: I don't think that what you say is correct: there is clearly a time dependent coefficient.

Comment: ? where? have you absorbed it to the dummy integration variable?

Comment: There is nothing that cancels the exponent in the second line that you wrote in your answer.

Comment: ? The prefactor of the cosine is collapsed to 0 by the δ, no?

Comment: Not identically: there is a measure 0 set of times in which it won't.

Comment: I don't see how is that fine. Do you claim that unitarity still persists at these specific times?

Comment: Yes, unitarity persists at all times, even for periodic motion. You must adapt your expressions for the half period. Was ***that*** the point of your question? You surely need to overhaul it drastically, or start another one on the topic. There are good texts to read on this, of course.

Comment: Yes, my point is that unitarity seems to be unclear at a certain times.

Comment: you probably won't trust me, but I claim that any try to claim that unitarity is preserved at these points is a bluff.

Comment: If you don't mind, I will send you a detailed draft showing that explicitly.

Comment: It is never late to correct an old mistake ;). My idea has actually already been confirmed with some top physicists, so you can trust me.